# NameError -- not definied

Tags: python, variables, definition, nameerror

Main Program

```
# import statements
import random
import winning

# Set constants
win = 0
lose = 0
tie = 0

ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSOR = 3

# Main Program for the Rock Paper Scissor game.
def main():
    # set variable for loop control
    again = 'y'

    while again == 'y':
        # Display menu
        display_menu()
        # prompt for user input
        userSelection = input('Which would you like to play with (1, 2, 3)?: ') 
        computerSelection = random.randint(1, 3) 

        # Call winner module to decide the winner!
        print(winning.winner(userSelection, computerSelection))

        # Ask to play again and make selection
        again = input('Would you like to play again (y/n)?')


def display_menu():
    print('Please make a selection: ')
    print(' 1) Play Rock')
    print(' 2) Play Paper')
    print(' 3) Play Scissor')



# Call main
main()
```

Second file: winning.py:

```
# This module will decide on who won based on input from Main

def winner(userInput, computerInput):
    if userInput == ROCK and computerInput == SCISSOR:
        print('You win!  Rock crushes Scissor!')
        win += 1
    elif userInput == SCISSOR and computerInput == PAPER:
        print('You win!  Scissor cuts Paper!')
        win += 1
    elif userInput == PAPER and computerInput == ROCK:
        print('You win!  Paper covers Rock!')
        win += 1
    elif userInput == computerInput:
        print('You tied with the computer! Please try again!')
        tie += 1
    else:
        print('You lost! Please try again!')
        lose += 1
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/RPS_Project/Main.py", line 14, in <module>
    ROCK = r
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

I have tried quotation marks and all, and cannot figure this out!!!  any help with this?
Please and thank you!

Comment: Please provide coherent information. The traceback has nothing in common with the code...and once again: we are not doing your homework

Comment: @Alli Err... "ROCK = r" is not in the code you posted. Please post the actually broken code. As posted, it should run fine, since it sets ROCK to 1.

Comment: not asking for anyone to do my homework.  I'm just asking for help learning.  I apologize and will not use this site any more for assistance understand what I am doing wrong...  Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Alli: The code you posted does not generate the error you posted.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that you're posting the wrong traceback for your code, or vice versa.

Comment: I am now getting an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/RPS_Project/Main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python32/RPS_Project/Main.py", line 28, in main
    print(winning.winner(userSelection, computerSelection))
  File "C:/Python32/RPS_Project\winning.py", line 19, in winner
    return lose
NameError: global name 'lose' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @Alli OGrady: your information was and remains *incoherent*

Comment: @Alli! you have to define `lose` too! You have to define _every variable name you use_.

Comment: Thank you...  I have it working now...  I appreciate all the help that was offered.  I apologize again for incoherent information.  In the future if I post, I will try to make everything as coherent as I can.  Thank you...  Alli

Answer (score 3):

Don't take the negative comments the wrong way. Just be sure to mark your homework as homework and be sure to paste the actual error generated by the code that you've posted. This error doesn't match the code you posted.

You might also ask your question in a slightly calmer-seeming way :)

The problem is very simple. You define your globals in the main program but not in `winning.py`, so lines like

```
if userInput == ROCK and computerInput == SCISSOR:
    print('You win!  Rock crushes Scissor!')
    win += 1
```

are going to cause NameErrors, because `ROCK`, `SCISSOR` and `win` are not defined. In every module, you *must* either define or import all the names you want to use; names are not shared between modules automatically -- for good reason!

I'll save you some trouble by telling you that you must also `return` a value from `winning.winner` -- otherwise, you won't get the output you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I will make sure that all help has "homework in the title from now on.

Comment: Thank you Senderle...  you were very helpful.